# ServiceStack AutoQuery AutoFilter Like operand

Tags: c#, servicestack, servicestack-autoquery, autoquery-servicestack

I am trying to implement SQL **Like** operator using AutoFilter attribute. Tried the below code,

```
[AutoFilter(field:"Name", Template = "{Field} like {Value}",  ValueFormat = "%{0}%")]
```

and the transformed SQL Expression looks like this (from SQL Profiler),

```
WHERE ("Table"."Name" = @0) AND ("Table"."Name" = @1)',N'@0 nvarchar(4000),@1 varchar(8000)',@0=NULL,@1='denver'
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried `QueryTerm.And,QueryTerm.Or` and `QueryTerm.Default` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `[QueryDbField]` for [Customizable Adhoc Queries](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#customizable-adhoc-queries).